# Footer in end of page

Tags: html, css, footer

I made  a div have class footer and want footer to be in the end of the page not fixed actually.

it is showing when the data of content element finish , i mention min-height of content equal t 90% so that if there is no more data then also in this case footer should be end of the page.

here is my css code

```
.header-cont 
{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
}
.header {
height:50px;
background:#3399FF;
border:1px solid #CCC;
width:100%;
margin:0px auto;
text-align:center;
```

}

```
.footer{
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
width:100%;
background-color: #3399FF;
height:35px;
} 
.footer-data
{   
padding:7px;
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
}

.content{
min-height:90%;
width:1130px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
top:80px;
margin-right:155px;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:125px;
}
```

HTML code

```
 <div class="header-cont">

 <div class="header">

</div>

</div>

<div class="content">

</div>

<div class="footer">

<div class="footer-data">
footer data
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can find a good example here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Danko didn't get you, support limit means?

Comment: You need to suport wich version of IE?

Comment: @Danko i am running my code in chorme and firefox.